# Distance between projections

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, projective-geometry

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb R^2$ such that $||x|| = ||y||= ||z|| = 1$.  Project $z$ onto the lines defined by $x$ and $y$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
z_x = (z^\text{T}x) x, \ \ z_y = (z^\text{T}y) y,
\end{equation}

Is it necessarily true that $||z_x - z_y|| \leq ||z|| = 1$?  If so, how can we prove it?

(If the answer can be generalized to $\mathbb R^n$, that would be cool too...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## $\mathbb{R}^2$

Fix $z$, let $x$ run around the unit circle, and forget $y$ for now.

The locus of projections of $z$ on $x$ is the circle with diameter 1 containing the origin and $z$.

[image]

The same locus for $y$.

Since the diameter is $||z||=1$, any two points are no farther away from each other than 1. QED.

## $\mathbb{R}^n$

The projection $z_{xy}$ of $z$ on the $xy$ plane is no longer than $z$ and the statement follows from the above for $z_{xy}$.

PS. The details are left for the reader...

Comment: There must be a purely algebraic way to say the same. Indeed, if we look at $||z_x - {1\over2}z||$ and $||z_y - {1\over2}z||$, we found each of them to be just ${1\over2}||z||$, so...

Comment: yep, this is equivalent to my solution.

Comment: Great!  Thanks, sds!